# Batch Files - Error Handling

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently writing my first batch file for deploying an asp.net solution.
I've been Googling a bit for a general error handling approach and can't find anything really useful.

Basically if any thing goes wrong I want to stop and print out what went wrong.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 100):

I generally find the conditional command concatenation operators much more convenient than ERRORLEVEL.

```
yourCommand && (
  echo yourCommand was successful
) || (
  echo yourCommand failed
)
```

There is one complication you should be aware of. The error branch will fire if the last command in the success branch raises an error.

```
yourCommand && (
  someCommandThatMayFail
) || (
  echo This will fire if yourCommand or someCommandThatMayFail raises an error
)
```

The fix is to insert a harmless command that is guaranteed to succeed at the end of the success branch. I like to use `(call )`, which does nothing except set the ERRORLEVEL to 0. There is a corollary `(call)` that does nothing except set the ERRORLEVEL to 1.

```
yourCommand && (
  someCommandThatMayFail
  (call )
) || (
  echo This can only fire if yourCommand raises an error
)
```

See [Foolproof way to check for nonzero (error) return code in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10935693/1012053) for examples of the intricacies needed when using ERRORLEVEL to detect errors.

Comment: Would u mind to provide a simple example with copy or del commands, pls?

Comment: Much nicer than keeping track of `ERRORLEVEL`, thanks!

Comment: I tried it with del but it always outputs that it was successful even though the file was not there

Comment: @Xerus - yes, the DEL (or ERASE) command is seriously flawed in that it always sets ERRORLEVEL to 0 and does not fire `||` as long as the arguments are valid, even if the delete fails. However, it does print an error message to stderr if the delete fails. You can do the following to detect a DEL stderr message (note the inverse logic) `DEL "yourFile" 2>&1 >nul|findstr "^" >nul && echo FAIL || echo OK`

Comment: I have done the same thing for avoiding the automatic exit of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: This is nice and clean and works well. The only slight issue I had was that `(call )` throws an error in a Visual Studio Post-Build script. Replacing it with a slightly-ambiguous-looking `call ` ("call" followed by a space) worked. (I added a comment above this line to explain it my future self!)

Comment: great info... I never remember the && and || for batch files... ;-) way better than checking ERRORLEVEL...

Answer (score 12):

Using ERRORLEVEL when it's available is the easiest option. However, if you're calling an external program to perform some task, and it doesn't return proper codes, you can pipe the output to 'find' and check the errorlevel from that.

```
c:\mypath\myexe.exe | find "ERROR" >nul2>nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo. Uh oh, something bad happened
exit /b 1
)
```

Or to give more info about what happened

```
c:\mypath\myexe.exe 2&1> myexe.log
find "Invalid File" "myexe.log" >nul2>nul && echo.Invalid File error in Myexe.exe && exit /b 1
find "Error 0x12345678" "myexe.log" >nul2>nul && echo.Myexe.exe was unable to contact server x && exit /b 1
```

Comment: At first view, I did not get that one. To save some minutes for others, it means:
If the command looking for "ERROR" in a previous output is successful (ERRORLEVEL is NOT >= 1, so any return code other than 0 is covered) it shows you the message "..something bad happened" and it returns status code 1 what informs the calling procedure that there was an error.

Answer (score 9):

Other than ERRORLEVEL, batch files have no error handling.  You'd want to look at a more powerful scripting language.  I've been moving code to [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).

The ability to easily use .Net assemblies and methods was one of the major reasons I started with PowerShell.  The improved error handling was another.  The fact that Microsoft is now requiring all of its server programs (Exchange, SQL Server etc) to be PowerShell drivable was pure icing on the cake.

Right now, it looks like any time invested in learning and using PowerShell will be time well spent.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I had done it using power shell, have a felling hacking a batch script is not time well spent..

Comment: No doubt that PowerShell is a superior language. But ERRORLEVEL is not the only recourse for batch - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17085933/1012053)

Comment: I tried the same in Azure DevOps by moving code from CommandLine tasks to Powershell Tasks but for some reason try/catch blocks did nothing. I still need to figure out why they didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

A successful ping on your local network can be trapped using `ERRORLEVEL`.

```
@ECHO OFF
PING 10.0.0.123
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO NOT-THERE
ECHO IP ADDRESS EXISTS
PAUSE
EXIT
:NOT-THERE
ECHO IP ADDRESS NOT NOT EXIST
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this feature was added since the OP but for future reference errors that would output in the command window can be redirected to a file independent of the standard output

command 1> file - Write the standard output of command to file

command 2> file - Write the standard error of command to file

Answer (score -2):

Python Unittest, Bat process Error Codes:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
   test_suite.addTest(RunTestCases("test_aggregationCount_001"))
   runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
   result = runner.run(test_suite)
   # result = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test_suite)
   if result.wasSuccessful():
       print("############### Test Successful! ###############")
       sys.exit(1)
   else:
       print("############### Test Failed! ###############")
       sys.exit()
```

Bat codes:

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,2) do (
testcase_test.py && (
  echo Error found. Waiting here...
  pause
) || (
  echo This time of test is ok.
)
)
```

Answer (score -8):

Its extremely easy!
Create a file that contains:

```
call <filename>  // the file you made
cls
echo An error occured!
<Your commands>
pause
```

So now when you start it, it will launch your program as normal. But when anything goes wrong it exits and continues the script inside the first file. Now there you can put your own commands in.