# what does "Child process exited with code 1" mean?

Tags: javafx, java-17, jpackage

I built the .exe file by Jpackage and WIX on Windows10(JDK17,JavaFX17).Then it shows "Child process exited with code 1"

[image]

this is my Jpackage command:
`jpackage --name test --input target --main-jar mechanical-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --icon src/main/resources/images/logo.ico --vendor J --win-dir-chooser --win-shortcut --win-menu-group "test" --win-menu`

I can't find any log or other information.

Comment: Does the `--verbose` command line option provide any more useful information?

Comment: If it's the executable built by `jpackage` that's failing, see if adding `--win-console` to the `jpackage` command and then running the resulting executable from the terminal provides any insights (e.g., an error/stack trace, which if one does appear, then you should [edit] your question to add it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that i can't get useful information about the error.
So we can add `--win-console` to jpackage command and rebuild.Then the terminal will provide error trace.

Comment: Another approach is to add logging to your application and configure the framework to log to a file. Depending on when exactly the application fails, that will cause the error to be logged to the file so you can see it without having to deal with `--win-console`. Of course, assuming you actually log the error.

Comment: @Slaw Yes,thank you for your notice! A log file is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[non-zero exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) means the process failed.

Sometimes a specific code can provide some insight into the reason for failure. In this case it does not.

See: [What "standard" application return/exit codes should an application support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538884/what-standard-application-return-exit-codes-should-an-application-support)

You probably want more information on why the `jpackage` process failed.  However, given the information already provided in your question, there is no additional information which can be provided here.

Comment: Wait, is it `jpackage` that's failing, or the executable built by `jpackage` that's failing?

Comment: The message says a child process failed, so it could be a spawned process as part of the packaging, such as Wix.  There is still not enough info to diagnose and fix the issue though.

Comment: Thank you all! I've got the solution and answered it.

Comment: I see now @Slaw you were correct.  Based on the info in the accepted self-answer, this was an error that occurred during execution of the packaged application and not during the packaging of the application.