# exit code bash commands env and pwd with an invalid option

Tags: bash, exit-code

These two errors are not treated in the same manner.
One has told me that *env* is not a builtin in bash.
Why the exit codes are different ?

`pwd -y`

bash: pwd: -y: invalid option

`echo $?`

2

`env -y`

env: invalid option -- 'y'

`echo $?`

125

I use GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).
I don't find the response on google.
I'd like just to understand it.

Comment: There are no standard exit codes, except that `0` means "no error". Every program decides which non-zero codes to use for its errors.

Comment: They're different programs; why shouldn't they have different exit status on failures? There's no real standard about that (other than 0 indicating success).

Comment: These are two completely different things. See `type pwd env`.

Comment: [GNU `env`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) is documented as exiting with 125-127 on various errors; otherwise it's whatever the program it runs returns. The bash [`pwd` built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-pwd) says *The return status is zero unless an error is encountered while determining the name of the current directory or an invalid option is supplied.* but nothing about the specific value.

Comment: Also see [What "standard" application return/exit codes should an application support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538884/4154375).