# multiple files in sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a list of sql files executing thru `SQLCMD` in batch file.

The batch file (.bat) file contains below sample script:

```
SQLCMD -i master.sql
```

master.sql contains

```
:r script1.sql
:r script2.sql
```

If any error occurs in `script1`, I need to proceed with `script2` but it stops at `script1` with an error msg. How can I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch Files - Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164049/batch-files-error-handling) and you can check the [ERRORLEVEL](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php)

Answer (score -1):

Are we talking MSSQL? In that case you might want to investigate Transact ( A built in programming language ). At any rate, using any if else structure might prove to be the solution you're looking for.

Kind Regards,

D.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm quite okay someone disagrees, but please explain why :s