# Test failure of DOS del D:\folder\*.ext

Tags: cmd, dos

Is there something that can go instead of ??? here to make this work?

del D:\folder*.ext
 if ??? goto fail

Else what's the better way to branch in fail? I'm hoping there's better than using a FOR loop.

Comment: Two questions: (1) what are you trying to do? (2) Really MS-DOS?

Comment: This question seems to be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164049/batch-files-error-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
del "D:\folder\*.ext" 
if exist "D:\folder\*.ext" goto :fail
goto :EOF

:fail
echo "D:\folder\*.ext" wasn't deleted
pause
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't find any documentation to say that wildcards are allowed in the FilenName parameter, but it works, so I'll got with it!