# How to store execution status of a specflow scenario when executed using Command Prompt

Tags: specflow

I'm trying to initiate the execution in a remote machine for which i want to get the execution status of a specflow scenario when executed using Command Prompt.
**Note:** I'm achieving this using TCPClient & TCPListener approach.

In this approach, i would like to pass the scenario tag like testcase id as - @1234 via TcpClient and in TCPListener i will listen to that tag number and will pass down such that i will execute via command prompt.

Here, i would like to get the Scenario execution status like Pass, failed, pending... such that i can pass it back to TcpClient and i can complete end to end testing...

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your requirements. Could you specify them more in detail.

Comment: @AndreasWillich - I am sorry, i'll try to put it simple. I want to save the scenario execution status to a local variable when i'm executing Specflow scenarios using Command Prompt..

Comment: Hope this explains more better - 1) Ill initiate specflow execution from MachineA using Visual Studio and in one of the step, ill connect to MachineB (will achieve this using TcpClient & TcpListener approach to connect both machines in which both are in same network.).
2) When i call from MachineA, i am sending the tag number which i need to execute the scenario which is associated to in MachineB. As i have tag number, i can execute that particular tag numbered scenario in MachineB. To do this i have to send that tag number via Command Prompt execution.

Comment: Continuation: 

Here i was stuck on how to save the scenario execution status such that after execution done in MachineB, ill return to machineA and can decide whether i can continue with other steps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running the testing using command prompt you can check for the error level. Following link might be helpful for the same:[Batch Files - Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164049/batch-files-error-handling)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After doing much browsing, came up with a solution - reading the console output and getting the status of the scenario from it.